# Regular expression to find two sets of 11 only

Tags: regex

Hello guys I need to find a regular expression that takes strings with two sets of 11 only
from a set {0,1,2}

```
0011110000          match it only has two sets
0010001001100       does not match (only has one set)
0000011000110011    does not match (it has three sets)
00                  does not match (it has no set
0001100000110001    match it only has two sets
```

This is what I've done so far

```
([^1]|1(0|2|3)(0|2|3)*)*11([^1]|1(0|2|3)(0|2|3)*)*11([^1]|1(0|2|3)(0|2|3)*|1$)*
                                                     --------------------------
```

I think what I'm missing is that I need to make sure the underlined section of the above regular expression has to make sure there is no more "11" left in the string, and I don't think that section is working correctly.

Comment: Apparently you mean non-overapping sets, right?  Also, do you or do you not have 3s in your string?

Answer (score 3):

If this is not homework, then I would suggest avoiding a regex and going with a regular function (shown here is JavaScript):

```
function hasTwoElevensOnly(s) {
    var first = s.indexOf("11");
    if (first < 0) return false;
    var second = s.indexOf("11", first + 2);
    if (second < 0) return false;
    return s.indexOf("11", second + 2) < 0;
}
```

Code here: http://jsfiddle.net/8FMRH/

```
function hasTwoElevensOnly(s) {
    return /^((0|1(?!1)|2)*?11(0|1(?!1)|2)*?){2}$/.test(s);
}
```

If a regex is required,

COde here: http://jsfiddle.net/PAARn/1/

Answer (score 3):

You *could* use a regular expression, but you've got much simpler options available to you. Here's an example in C#:

```
public bool IsValidString(string input)
{
   return input.Split(new string[] { "11" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Length == 3;
}
```

Although regular expressions can be a very useful tool, their usage is not always warranted. As [jwz put it](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Comment: This fFails if "11" is at the start or end of the string.  You could add a dumy "0" to either end of the string first to compensate for that.

Comment: The Zawinski quote is also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640/great-programming-quotes

Comment: @Hand-E-Food No, it should handle those cases properly. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Donut: Pardon me, you're right.  I'm really not on the ball today.

Answer (score 1):

most of regex comes with the restriction of appearance, usually in `{}`. For example, in JavaScript, you could do something like:

```
/^((10|0)*11(01|0)*){2}$/
```

Which mataches 2 set of `11` prefixed and suffixed with 0+ `0` in the string.

Comment: This fails to match 001100000100000110000.

Comment: well...what about 0011100110? does that need to be matched?

Comment: I would think so because the OP said 1111 _does_ match so that means no overlap. 111011, under the no-overlap condition does have two sets.  But good question; ask the OP.

Comment: well, assuming 111 matches, the updated answer should be closer to the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

There may be a simpler way, but starting with your approach, this seems to work on the sample data provided:

```
/^([^1]|1[023])*11([^1]|1[023])*11((?<!11)|1[023]|[023]|(?<=[023])1)*$/
```

Using lookbehind.